# How to add image to Menuitem using Swings

Tags: java, image, swing, jmenuitem

I  have MenuItem.here in that i want to add one image to menuitem.So can you please suggest Me?

```
                    MenuItem view = new MenuItem("View");
                    MenuItem setting = new MenuItem("Settings");
                    MenuItem logout = new MenuItem("Logout");


                    popup.add(view);
                    popup.addSeparator();
                    popup.add(setting);
                    popup.addSeparator();
                    popup.add(logout);
```

In Left side of logout,i want one image.so how can i do?

Comment: Probably you use a wrong class. Try to use `JMenuItem` instead of `MenuItem`

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this:

```
logout.setIcon(new ImageIcon("icon.png"));
```

with **icon.png** being the path to your actual image file.

Answer (score 3):

MenuItem is an AWT component, not a Swing component

Within JMenuItem, you can use [AbstractButton.setIcon(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon-javax.swing.Icon-)

```
JMenuItem item =...;
ImageIcon icon =...;
item.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: JMenuItem has also constructor with Icon